# MECL on iOS with new API credential on developer.paypal.com

Tags: ios, paypal

I wrote a app which pay with PayPal few months ago.I followed the guide on x.com and created several test account to test my app.
But I noticed that they moved lots of contents to their new web side developer.paypal.com(Maybe not?) and I found that my test accounts are gone.
I can not find them at anywhere on x.com,I wrote one of them in my code comment before and it is still valid.
The PROBLEM is --when I trying to create a test account in the new website and use its credential and API name/password in MECL,the response is the security head is not valid.Did I miss something?Or they're totally two notion?

BTW:Is there any way to get my old test account Back on x.com?